# Call an activity using Alarm Manager & Broadcast Receiver

Tags: broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I'm trying to create an app that automatically make phone calls after regular intervals to a specified number. I'm using Alarm Manager and Broadcast Receiver for this purpose. Alarm Manager can't initiate PHONE CALL activity and application terminates giving an error.

Here's my code. I am new in this Dev this.

*MainActivity.java

```
import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView label;
    private EditText phoneNum;
    private PendingIntent pendingIntent;
    private AlarmManager manager;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        label=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.entertextlabel);
        phoneNum=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.phonenofield);
        Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, alarmIntent, 0);
        //pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,1,alarmIntent,0);

            }

    public void startAlarm(View view) {
        manager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        int interval = 10000;

        manager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), interval, pendingIntent);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Alarm Set", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }


    public void cancelAlarm(View view) {
        if (manager != null) {
            manager.cancel(pendingIntent);
            Toast.makeText(this, "Alarm Canceled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

*AlarmReceiver.java

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.widget.Toast;

/**
 * Created by Saud on 05/11/2015.
 */
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent arg1) {
        // For our recurring task, we'll just display a message
       Toast.makeText(context, "I'm running", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent in = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
        in.setData(Uri.parse("tel:03324310929"));
        context.startActivity(in);


    }

}
```

I'm getting error "Call requires user permission...."
at

```
context.startActivity(in);
```

*mainactivity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Enter the Mobile number"
        android:id="@+id/entertextlabel"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="79dp" />    

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Start Alarm"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/callBtn"
        android:layout_marginBottom="81dp"
        android:onClick="startAlarm"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Cancel Alarm"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/callBtn"
        android:onClick="cancelAlarm"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

*Mantifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.saud.nexustelecom" >


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver"></receiver>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is resolved.

I used the Flag "FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK" with with the intent in AlarmReceiver class.

New code is as follows

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.widget.Toast;

/**
 * Created by Saud on 05/11/2015.
 */
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent arg1) {
        // For our recurring task, we'll just display a message
       Toast.makeText(context, "I'm running", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       // Intent in = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
        //in.setData(Uri.parse("tel:03324310929"));
        Intent in = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
        in.setData(Uri.parse("tel:03324310929"));
        in.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(in);


    }

}
```